# UIActivityIndicatorView is black

Tags: xamarin, tvos

In a Xamarin.tvOS project I'm working on, we're using a UIActivityIndicatorView on a splash screen when the application first launches, and I recently noticed the color was black. The style is set to WhiteLarge, and I even assigned the color to white manually and it is still black at runtime.

I then tried manually assigning the color in ViewDidLoad() with `UIActivityIndicatorView.Color = UIColor.White` but it ignored that as well. What is really weird is that if I assign it to something like UIColor.Red, it will be red like I expect. Unless I'm mistaken, the default color of a UIActivityIndicatorView with the style of WhiteLarge should be white anyway, so this makes no sense to me...

Have I encountered some strange accessibility or theme color issue where the color is being reassigned somehow or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, my info.plist file was missing an entry called `User Interface Style` that is automatically added when creating newer Xamarin.tvOS projects that target tvOS 10 or above. When I added it and set it to `Automatic` (the other two options being `Light` or `Dark`), I began to see the behavior I expected.

I found this link to the Xamarin guide to User Interface Styles to be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/tvos/platform/user-interface-styles

Answer (score 0):

> Unless I'm mistaken, the default color of a UIActivityIndicatorView with the style of WhiteLarge should be white anyway, so this makes no sense to me...

On tvOS the users theme, `Settings -> General -> Theme`, will decide the `UIActivityIndicatorView`'s tint color by default.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I tried assigning the Settings -> General -> Appearance to both Light and Dark, it was still black. I also tried dragging out a brand new UIActivityIndicatorView into my .xib and it was also black on both Light and Dark appearance. Any ideas?

Comment: @RichardJones Are you forcing the users theme to `light` or `dark` in the application, or are you using the default `automatic` setting for the theme?

Comment: I am not forcing any themes in the application. You prompted me to search for a way to do so, which led me to finding out that I was missing a >= tvOS10 keyword in my info.plist that would alter the color of certain UI elements in applications that targeted tvOS 10 or above. Once I added that entry, it fixed my issue.

Comment: @RichardJones great, glad you found the solution! You should post it as an answer to your question for others.